# How to read Spaces from a file in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, file-read

I want to read all characters from a file including all spaces,  what i am trying is

```
fileRead = textread('myFile.txt', '%c');
disp('Characters total')
disp(length(fileRead))
```

But the result is not correct because its only counting all characters except space.

> So how do i do that, any help would be appreciated?

I want to read file with spaces.

[Image is attached here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7k4U0.png)

Comment: Except space? you are counting all of them, including space, rigth?

Comment: documentation says that if you use '%c' then it will include all spaces, but when i paste my txt file in MS word then it says a different result means it not counting spaces

Comment: I do trust MATLAB more than MS word, to be honest.... Can you post a [mcve]

Comment: @Ander Biguri: see details here https://i.stack.imgur.com/7k4U0.png Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the help on `textread` (or the better alternative `textscan`) isn't super clear on how the `%c` format specifier handles whitespace.

If you just use a single `%c`, it is going to read *one character at a time* but in this scenario, whitespace is still going to be treated as a delimiter since it falls between two single-character matches.

What the documentation is referring to about `%c` matching whitespace is that if you specify an expected length for the `%c` specifier (`%<length>c`), then whitespace will be included in the match.

```
textread('z.txt', '%12c')
%   my name is z
```

If you just want to read in an entire file as a character array, I would just use `fread` with the `'*char'` data type which is a low-level function for accessing file contents if you don't need to parse them at all.

```
fid = fopen('z.txt', 'r');
data = fread(fid, '*char').';

disp(numel(data))
```

If you really want to use `textread`, another option is to use the `%s` (string) format specifier instead of the character specifier and set the `'Whitespace'` parameter to `''` to not treat spaces as whitespace and therefore a delimeter.

```
textread('z.txt', '%s', 'whitespace', '')
```